# Is there any way to boot a .vdi file using VBoxManage without creating a new machine?

Tags: virtualbox

I've a `.vdi` file and I would like to boot it for some testing reason without actually creating a new virtual machine. Moreover, the user that has to boot it, do not have its own home, as he's a system user. So, I would like to boot it, shutdown it, and everything should be as if nothing happened.

Is it possibile to do it using `VBoxManage`?